# Django 3 ModelSerializier().data returns {}

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to create a route that returns some model properties as a JSON with the Django REST framework and filter them based on some properties. But I don't get the serializer to working properly.

```
class MaxQuantPathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta():
    model = MaxQuantRun
    fields = '__all__'
    depth=0

class MaxQuantPathsAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    filter_fields = ['project', 'setup']
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
            get_data = request.query_params
            queryset = MaxQuantRun.objects.filter(project=get_data['project'])
            serializer = MaxQuantPathSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            data = serializer.data
            return JsonResponse(data, status=201, safe=False)
```

The queryset returns some values but the serializer returns an empty dictionary.

I updated the code based on the comments below. Now, a json file is returned.

Comment: Try adding many=True, to `data = MaxQuantPathSerializer(queryset).data` => `data = MaxQuantPathSerializer(queryset, many=True).data`

Comment: Now I get: `n order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.`

Comment: Ok, got it........